# AFNetworking returning response in NSError object

Tags: iphone, ios, nsurlconnection, afnetworking

I was using NSURLConnection to consume service now I am switching to AFNetworking but getting some strange error. My code 
**Note: CTPHTTPClient is subclass of AFHTTPClient**

```
NSDictionary *parameters =  @{
                              @"email" : @"test@gyc.com",
                              @"confirmPassword" : @"12345",
                              @"userName" : @"mithilesh",
                              @"password" : @"12345",
                              @"termsAndConditionAccepted" : @1,
                              @"dob" : @"1190-03-05"
                              };

[[CTPHTTPClient sharedCTPHTTPClient] postPath:@"signup.json"
                                   parameters:parameters
                                      success: ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id JSON){


                                          NSLog(@"Res = %@",JSON);

                                      }
                                      failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){

                                          [CTPUtilities showAlert:[error localizedDescription] delegate:self];
                                      }];
```

**Response**

[image]

In above response you can see the red rectangle Its contain the valid response. I am getting it correctly when using NSURLConnection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is probably the server side sending a failure HTTP status code. Although you are sending the correct payload, you should be basing the status of your request on the status code, not on the payload's content. AFNetworking does this for you, and as the AFNetworking error says, the server returned 500.